# NoReverseMatch at /options/ Reverse for 'sales' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['sales/(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Tags: django

I am trying to learn django and I have encountered this error. It has persisted irrespective of the fact that I have tried the available SO remedies but for some reason, it refuses to go away. Can someone please see an error anywhere.

show_options.html

```
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-block bg-dark" style="color: black;"  href="{% url 'Management:addProduct' %}"> Add </a>
  **<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  href="{% url 'Management:sales' add_user_sales.pk %}"> Add Sales </a>**
  <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  href="{% url 'Management:total' %}"> View Total </a>
```

function to render my show_options page

```
def show_options(request):
    return render(request, 'show_options.html', {})
```

function add_user_sales

```
@login_required
def add_user_sales(request , pk):
    current_user = request.user
    context = {}
    context["data"] = MadeSale.objects.get(id=pk)
    profiles = UserProfile.get_profile()
    for profile in profiles:
        if profile.profile_name.id == current_user.id:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                form = SalesForm(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    upload = form.save(commit=False)
                    upload.posted_by = current_user
                    upload.profile = profile
                    upload.save()
                    messages.success(request, f'Hi, Your data has successfully been updated' )
                    return redirect('addProduct')
            else:
                form = SalesForm()
            return render(request,'addProduct.html',{"user":current_user,"form":form}, context)
```

my app urls

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token
app_name = 'Management'

url(r'^sales/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.add_user_sales, name='sales')
```

,

Comment: There likely is *no* `add_user_sales` in the context.

Comment: Hi @WillemVanOnsem. I wont ask how to do it, but according to the code, what would you suggest? I am really new to django and I can cant make out much from your comment.